# Passing multiple values of same parameter in .getJson()

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, youtube

I'm trying following:

```
<script>
  var topic_id = '/m/04136kj';
  var service_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/topic';
  var params = {
                filter: "/common/topic/article",
                filter:"/common/topic/notable_for",
                filter: "/common/topic/notable_types",
                filter: "/type/object/type"
               };

  $.getJSON(service_url + topic_id + '?callback=?', params, function(topic) {
    //do something with response.
  });
</script>
```

If you notice I've to pass 4 values for `filter`. But the final url that I captured from FIDDLER contains only last value (`/type/object/type`) I tried with only one param and it works fine(any param) but not with multiple values. How can I form correct param?

**EDIT:**

Passing an array like below in first answer encodes URL incorrectly. It adds `[]` after `filter` i.e it passes `filter[]=` in URL and not `filter=`

```
var params = {
           filter: ["/common/topic/article", "/common/topic/notable_for",
                      "/common/topic/notable_types", "/type/object/type"]
           };
```

Answer (score 1):

create the filter object as an array

```
var topic_id = '/m/04136kj';
var service_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/topic';
var params = {
    filter: ["/common/topic/article", "/common/topic/notable_for", "/common/topic/notable_types", "/type/object/type"]
};
//used to remove the the suffix [] in the array param
$.ajaxSetup({ traditional: true });
$.getJSON(service_url + topic_id + '?callback=?', params, function (topic) {
    //do something with response.
});
```

Comment: Thanks. It works and I understood the logic. That's really stupid of me :D

Comment: One small question. Url is encoded like this: `https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/topic/m/04136kj?callback=jsonp1403174148707&filter[]=/common/topic/article` I notice a `[]` after filter. Do you know why?

Comment: I confirmed with fiddler. It is passing `[]` with filter and that's causing an incorrect response. Any idea?

Comment: Downvoting because it's not an answer to the question due to the embedded `[]`

Answer (score 0):

The param object needs to be created as if it was an HTML `<form>` object, as a series of name/value pairs.

```
var topic_id = '/m/04136kj';
var service_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/topic';
var filter = ["/common/topic/article", "/common/topic/notable_for",
    "/common/topic/notable_types", "/type/object/type"];
var params = filter.map(function(f) { return { name: "filter", value: f }; });

$.getJSON(service_url + topic_id + '?callback=?', params, function (topic) {
    //do something with response.
});
```